# how do you get jsp page dedicated to launching a JNLP file create a browser popup?

Tags: java, jsp, jnlp

if the top of your JSP reads

```
<%@ page contentType="application/x-java-jnlp-file"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How do you add html to this page?

Equally, How would you get the web browser to create a popup for instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write a regular servlet for it? JNLP files are not html and i dont even know how that would work with JSP.

And if you send a JNLP most web browsers will know what to do with it, you can also distribute this file through email(or other means) and start it directly on the users computer.

I used to have several WebStart apps a few years ago and i wrote a servlet that would just serve the JNLP file from the local file system. I later changed it to generate the JNLP file on the fly and include default libraries i used in all my projects. I also used that to serve the jars from the file system so they didnt need to be bundled with the servlet WAR.

I put some of my code here http://ideone.com/36sjB as a start. Most of it was used in an experimental in house app, so this should not be used in production code ;).

Sending the JNLP is just like sending the jar with a different content type. I also have code about generating the JNLP from scratch through the servlet if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you add html to this page?

If you do, it won't be a JNLP file.  It will be a mess that is pretending (poorly) to be a JNLP.  Most JWS clients would reject it, pointing out that it is not JNLP, the rest would fail with other (less obvious) errors.

> Equally, How would you get the web browser to create a popup for instructions?

Aaaargh, the dreaded pop-ups.  My browser would kill them automatically.

---

Put instructions on *the page that links to the JSP* that launches the app.